# Make decoration div with border stretch down to top of sticky footer

Tags: html, css, height, footer, article

(Note: My question has not been asked anywhere on the internet as far as I can see, and I've been searching for almost two days.)

I have a content div with translucent background and decorative border around it that sits perfectly under the site logo, but won't stretch down to meet the top portion of the footer which is stuck to the bottom of the page with position absolute. This is a Contact page with a couple sentences of text and a simple contact form, therefore not enough content to fill up the whole page.

Specifically, I need a div with a border around it to fill up the whole page, without creating a vertical scroll bar, and meet the top of a absolutely positioned footer.

The rest of the site does not use an absolutely positioned footer as there is enough content to consistently push the footer far down. So, any CSS properties are acceptable here, even a table hack if necessary!

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NightSpark/j909r64j/)

```css
header {
    height: 44px;
    background: orange;
}

article {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 1px solid red; 
}

footer {
    height: 22px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
header
</header>
<article>
article with small amount of content<br>
<br>
and a simple contact form<br>
<br>
this red border needs to meet the top of the footer<br>
without creating a vertical scroll bar
</article>
<footer>
footer
</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use css3 to set the height of your "article" to 100% minus both header and footer height (in this case 66px) like this:

```
height:calc(100% - 66px);
```

Just be sure that every parent of the article element have the height set to 100% (including html and body).

your modified **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j909r64j/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer using position fixed. I think Alvaro Menendez has a better answer though

```
article {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  position:fixed;
  top:50px; /* size of header */
  right:0;
  bottom:30px; /* size of footer */
  left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j909r64j/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may use either [display:table](http://jsfiddle.net/j909r64j/3/) or [display:flex](http://jsfiddle.net/j909r64j/4/) to easily achieve your basic layout.

the table like version:

```css
header {
    height: 44px;
    background: orange;
}
article {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
footer {
    height: 22px;
    background: green;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
header, article, footer {
    display:table-row;
}
article {
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
    <header>header</header>
    <article>article with small amount of content
        <br>
        <br>and a simple contact form
        <br>
        <br>this red border needs to meet the top of the footer
        <br>without creating a vertical scroll bar</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
```

and the flex version

```css
header {
    height: 44px;
    background: orange;
}
article {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
footer {
    height: 22px;
    background: green;
}
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
   
}
body { 
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

article {
    flex:1;
}
```

```html
    <header>header</header>
    <article>article with small amount of content
        <br>
        <br>and a simple contact form
        <br>
        <br>this red border needs to meet the top of the footer
        <br>without creating a vertical scroll bar</article>
    <footer>footer</footer>
```